# Transliteration/Transcription of מְלאוּפּם

Tags: hebrew, transcription, transliteration, yiddish

[image]

Notice that there is no vowel point under the פּ. This should probably be considered to be because of the fact that Hebrew is usually written without vowels, but I've never seen it written *with* a vowel there (at least with all the other points being the same), and in Yiddish this symbol is called a "melupm vov." Would it be feasible in a completely "mechanical" transliteration/transcription (i.e. one where every letter/sound is always written the same in Latin characters) to write a short vowel like "i" or "u" there? If not, can you give me a source for it being written "m'loopm"?

Answer (score 2):

That `וּ` niqqud [is called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubutz_and_Shuruk) "Melopum" (מלאפום) in Ashkenazi tradition.

In *A Comprehensive Etymological Dictionary of the Hebrew Language for Readers of English*, 1987, by Ernest Klein, the word מלאפום is found on page 348:

[image: melopun]

Your variant, מלאופם, is absent in that dictionary.

As you can see, the word in your picture has the `וּ` *before* פּ, while Wikipedia and Ernest Klein's dictionary have it *after* פּ. Whatever the reason, Google search gives [3,440 results](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1IHCB_enUA879UA879&sxsrf=ALeKk00Ij5lJk9PuCiUvsbDh3BUc4yzlkQ%3A1596909812611&ei=9OguX5bsJOz4qwGniLyAAQ&q=%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%9D&oq=%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%9D&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzIICAAQBRAeEBM6AggAOgIILjoECCMQJzoKCAAQDRAFEB4QE1CdO1jkxgFgotYBaABwAHgAgAHaAYgBjAiSAQUyLjQuMZgBAKABAqABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiWtvnQmIzrAhVs_CoKHScEDxAQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) for מלאפום vs. [66 results](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1IHCB_enUA879UA879&sxsrf=ALeKk03ZVuCTxbzrBFgOydswUF0nBqgpkg%3A1596909842214&ei=EukuX6bgDJa53APEvK3YCg&q=%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%9D&oq=%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%9D&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1CUnwJYlJ8CYKqqAmgAcAB4AIABxQOIAcUDkgEDNC0xmAEAoAECoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwimsYjfmIzrAhWWHHcKHUReC6sQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) for מלאופם. Either your variant is real, but extremely rare, or it's just a typo, 2 letters switched, וּ and פּ, which is a common thing.

Comment: Can you find a source for rendering this as "m'lopoom" in Latin letters? I can't...

Comment: @user17584 - You won't find it, nobody renders the Hebrew [u] as “oo”, it's only you who do it. I've given you a reference to Wikipedia where it's called "Melopum", how isn't it enough?

Comment: What do you mean "nobody renders the Hebrew [u] as 'oo'"? Here's just one example: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Hebrew/Introduction/Alphabet I'm pretty certain that my variant is real given Yiddish "melupm vov."

Comment: @user17584 - that book is a basic textbook, it explains the Hebrew sounds by using the English spelling. It is only in such explanatory books that you'll see "oo" in Hebrew words, serious books use more traditional kinds of transliteration or IPA transcription. That book is an excellent reference for rendering מְלָאפוּם as "m'lopoom", because it's exactly how that word is pronounced according to that book.

Comment: The point is that it is _not_ called "melopum" in Ashkenazi tradition. You don't explain the /u/.